# Make functions with line break in their first line fold in Vim

Tags: vim, code-folding

I am using `foldmethod=syntax` in my `.vimrc` file. It works well with C functions like this one:

```
int some_fun(int i) {
  return i;
}
```

However, it won't work with functions, which have a break line in the first line:

```
int some_fun2(int i,
  int i2) {
  return i;
}
```

Can I make Vim understand that fold should begin not where `{` is but where the function definition begins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you have to augment the `syntax/c.vim` syntax file with a proper definition. The following line is responsible for the default behavior of folding `{...}` blocks:

```
syn region    cBlock      start="{" end="}" transparent fold
```

You have to override that with one that considers function definitions (whose syntax patterns you'll also find in that file), and put that into `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`. A challenge with that is that the start match for the function definition will now obscure the default matching, so elements like `int` and the function name may lose its highlighting. Maybe a zero-width match may prevent that, or you can use the `matchgroup`. If all of that sounds to be well over your head, don't bother. Maybe the fact that you haven't found such syntax modification means that it's too hard to do.